# Erro ao inserir Dados com AngularJS

Tags: php, javascript, angularjs

Estou encontrando erros ao inserir dados com AngularJS

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Codigo Angular:**

```
 var myapp = angular.module('myapp',[]);

        myapp.controller('productController',function($scope,$http) {

//listar produtos
          $http.get("customers_mysql.php").then(function (response) {$scope.listProducts = response.data.records;});

//inserir produtos
              $scope.add = function(){

                    /*$scope.listProducts.push({
                        id:$scope.id,
                        name:$scope.name,
                        price:$scope.price,
                        quantity:$scope.quantity
                    });*/

                    $http.post("insert.php", {

                        'name':$scope.name,
                        'price':$scope.price,
                        'quantity':$scope.quantity})                    
                        .success(function(data,status,headers,config){
                            console.log("Data Inserted Successfully");
                        });

                    $scope.id       = '';
                    $scope.name     = '';
                    $scope.price    = '';
                    $scope.quantity = '';
                };
```

**Codigo PHP**

```
 <?php  
    $HOST  = "localhost";
    $LOGIN = "root";
    $SENHA = "";

    mysql_connect( $HOST, $LOGIN, $SENHA) or die("Não foi possível a conexão com o servidor");
    mysql_select_db("bancoteste") or die("Não foi possível selecionar o banco de dados");

    $data       = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    $name       = mysql_real_escape_string($data->name);
    $price      = mysql_real_escape_string($data->price);
    $quantity   = mysql_real_escape_string($data->quantity);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO tprodutos('name', 'price', 'quantity') VALUES('".$name."','".$price."','".$quantity."')";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);


    mysql_close();
?>
```

**Hospedagem do sistema**

http://crudangularjsphp.azurewebsites.net/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isso estava obsoleto há tempo e foi removido nas versões atuais do AngularJS. Vide [documentação oficial](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

Agora é preciso usar `.then` passando como primeiro parâmetro o *callback* caso a requisição seja bem sucedida e como segundo parâmetro o *callback* caso haja algum erro (substituindo o `error`).

```
$http.post("insert.php", seuObjeto).then(function() {
    console.log("Data Inserted Successfully");
});
```

Comment: Estou usando o angular.js 1.6 e tenho:

Comment: usei este codigo mas não funcionou:

Comment: $http.post("insert.php", {    
     'name':$scope.name,
     'price':$scope.price,
     'quantity':$scope.quantity}).then(function() {
     console.log("Data Inserted Successfully");
    });